# Python interpreter bugging out with error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' "

Tags: python, python-3.6, interpreter

I was making a programming language in Python 3.6 when I stumbled across something odd. With the following code, I get an error, with some interesting output.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

class _Viper:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def error(self, err, title="ERROR"):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title(title)
        root["bg"] = "#d56916"
        label = tk.Label(root, text=err)
        labelt = tk.Label(root, text=str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        label.config(bg="#e67a27")
        labelt.config(bg="#d56916")
        label.grid()
        labelt.grid()
        root.mainloop()
    def grabdata(self, line):
        raw = line.split("(")
        raw[1] = raw[1][:-1]
        print(type(raw[1]))
        raw[1] = raw[1].split()
        #raw[1] = raw[1].split('"')
        return {
            "keyword" : raw[0],
            "params"  : raw[1].split()
        }

Viper = _Viper() #For PyLint
"""
try:
    sys.argv[1]
    execute = True
except:
    execute = False
    Viper.error("Error `Viper.FileNotProvidedError` @ interpreter.py. Do not directly run this file. Run it with `Viper0.0.0a C:\\path\\to\\file`, or associate viper to Viper0.0.0a.bat.")
"""

sys.argv.append("C:\\viper\\interpreter\\testie.vi")
execute = True

if execute:
    extension = str(sys.argv[1][-2]+sys.argv[1][-1])
    if extension.upper() == "VI":
        with open("C:\\viper\\interpreter\\testie.vi", "r") as src:
            lines = src.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            Viper.grabdata(line)
    else:
        Viper.error("Error `Viper.ExtensionNotViperError` @ interpreter.py. Please run this with a file with the \"vi\" extension.")
```

After running this, I get this error.
[image: Error]

Are you seeing what I'm seeing? `<class 'str'>` is the class of `raw[1]`. Nothing there. But when I refer to it after, it says that it's a list!

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

### EDIT

*I forgot to add the viper file.*

```
setvar("hmm", "No")
```

### EDIT 2

I'm going to explain my issue. It's treating a **string** as a **list**.

Answer (score 1):

The line after you print the type:

```
 raw[1] = raw[1].split()
```

This turns it into a list.  When you call `raw[1]` later with `"params"  : raw[1].split()`, it is not a string anymore, but a list. So this means `raw[1]` is being split twice.  If you are intending to return the parameters in `raw[1]` as a list, you could just remove the line `raw[1] = raw[1].split()`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give me an example of how to fix it.

Comment: By changing it to `raw = raw[1].split()`, it removes the "keyword" which I do not want.

Comment: Do you have an example line of what you're splitting and what you're trying to get?

Comment: I added the viper file with the post.

Comment: I'm not sure the intention of the rest of the code, but this should have address the error.  Are you still getting the error?